# When I click on the load more button, new data comes, but the pictures remain fixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am preparing a react project for starships. When the user clicks the Load More button, I want the data on the 2nd page to come and the images of those ships to be loaded.

Currently, ship names are changing, but my images are not. What should I do for this?

These are my codes in App.js;

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import "../styles/Films.css";

class Films extends Component {

    state = {
        data: [],
        movieDetailsOpen: false,
        movieSelected: "",
        index: 0,
        page: 1,
        isLoading: false,
    };

    posterImages = [
        "CR90-Corvette.png",
        "stardestroyer.png",
        "Sentinel-class-landing-craft.jpg",
        "Death-Star.png",
        "Millenium_Falcon.jpg",
        "Y-wing.png",
        "x-wing.png",
        "TIE-Advanced-x1.png",
        "executor.png",
        "rebel-transport.png",
        "rebel-transport.png",
        "rebel-transport.png",
        "rebel-transport.png"
    ];

    async getFilms() {
        const {page} =this.state
        let data = [];
        this.setState({
            data: []
        });

        await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=${page}`)
            .then(async (res) => {
                let response = await res.json();
                data = [...data, response.results];
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        data[0].map((res, index) => {
            this.setState({
                data: [...this.state.data, res]
            });
            return res;
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getFilms();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { page } = this.state;
     
      }

      componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
        if (prevState.page !== this.state.page) {
          this.getFilms();
        }
      }

      loadMore = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          page: prevState.page + 1
        }));
    }; 
    render() {
        const {isLoading} = this.state;

        return (
            
            <div className="starships-wrapper">
                <div className="top" id="top">
                    <img src="./logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                </div>
                <div className="bottom" id="bottom">
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.data.map((res, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key={index}
                                        className="ship-list"
                                        style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.posterImages[index]})`}}
                                        >
                                        <div className="name">{res.name}</div>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            }
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="load-more">
                    <button onClick={this.loadMore} className="btn-grad" variant="dark">
                        {isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Load More'}
                    </button>
                            
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
                            
        
    }
}

export default Films;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide code that you've tried to solve your problem with.  Additionally, in order to answer your question effectively, we need more details.
1) What is the desired behavior? 2) What is currently happening? 3) What code have you tried?

Comment: `posterImages` is a hardcoded array, why would you expect it to "refresh" ?

Answer (score 0):

Poster images aren't going to change because the array isn't being changed. It's hardcoded. So I'm not sure what you are expecting to change.

Comment: Understood. If I use array will the pictures change? It would be more helpful if you could tell me what to use. I'm sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: poster images should come from your api, so new image will come with new data

Comment: ok but there is no image in the api. so I have to take the image externally, there is no problem with the first 10 images, but when I change the page, I have no idea how to change the images